# PowerShell 403 HTTP Request With Parameters Containing Square Brackets

Tags: powershell, http, https, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to make a PATCH request using the following lines in PowerShell but it is returning a 403:

```
Try{
    $Body = @{
       'api_key' = 'myapikey'
       'item[status]' = 'unavailable'
    } | ConvertTo-Json
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method PATCH -Uri "https://api.example.com/store/apikey.json" -Body $Body -ContentType "application/json"
    $response.StatusCode
}
Catch [System.Net.WebException]{
    $code = [int]$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode
}
```

Fiddler is returning a 403 with the following message: "{"error":"Parameter item is required"}". Also, the query string in Fiddler is empty. However, a successful request is made when everything is hard-coded into the Uri:

```
$statusUpdate = Invoke-WebRequest -Method PATCH -Uri "https://api.example.com/store/apikey.json?api_key=myapikey&item[status]=unavailable" -ContentType "application/json"
```

Comment: Did you try URL-encoding the parameter name?

Comment: Note (but unrelated to your issue) that using application/json as payload type for PATCH has undefined semantics.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers are you talking about this: [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode('item[status]') = 'unavailable'

If so, then yes, I have. It still returns a 403. The JSON request body will show as item%5bstatus%5d=unavailable in Fiddler.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Was just a shot in the dark, though.

Answer (score 2):

If that's the code you're actually using to hit the API, your problem appears to simply be due to piping your json body to out-host, thus sending an empty $Body to the API, so you should edit it to do this:

```
try
{
  $Body = @{
    'api_key' = 'myapikey'
    'item[status]' = 'unavailable'
  } | ConvertTo-Json
  $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method PATCH -Uri "https://api.example.com/store/apikey.json" -Body $Body -ContentType "application/json"
  $response.StatusCode
}
catch [System.Net.WebException]
{
  $code = [int]$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I used Out-Host to debug for that exact reason but it still returns a 403. Edited the original question to clear any confusions.